# I am trying to manipulate the pixel values without clipping them

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image which has a max pixel value - `287.4976094062538` and min pixel value - `-41.082841881780645` I am trying to bring them in range between `0-255`

what I did:-

- I have divided all the pixel values with max pixel value and then multiplied with 255
- this made my highest pixel value to 1 but my min pixel value is still in negative pixel value `-0.14`.

It is a medical image so I want to preserve every pixel intensities so I don't want to clip them between 0-255

but how can I bring them in that range without clipping(which damage the image structure).

loading them with library like `matplotlib` or `PIL` automatically clipping the pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are normalizing the positive range of your image only, ignoring the negative values.

You want to apply the following equation to your values:

```py
mx = np.amax(img)
mn = np.amin(img)
img = (img - mn) / (mx - mn) * 255
```

We're first subtracting the minimum value, so that the minimum value in the image becomes 0. Next we divide to set the maximum value to 1.
`mx-mn` is the full range of your data, and therefore the maximum value in the data after setting the minimum to 0.

Comment: This method works, however if different images has different pixel ranges, after this "normalizing", they will not be consistent across images. So you may want to find out or define an "absolute minimum value", say -100.0, and "absolute maximum value", say 1000.0, use them across all your images.

Answer (score 2):

Scikit-image has function for this:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity

It maybe better to rescale it to range (0,1), do all the processing in float format and convert to int8 before saving.

```
In [1]: from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
In [2]: from skimage import img_as_ubyte
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: im = np.random.uniform(low=-100, high=400, size=(3,3))

In [5]: im
Out[5]: 
array([[351.2177509 , 313.89196632, 241.73850855],
       [-21.12284801,  97.84166107, -66.925235  ],
       [267.75593733, -15.78767759, 252.63980599]])

In [6]: im = rescale_intensity(im, in_range='image', out_range=(0,1))

In [7]: im
Out[7]: 
array([[1.        , 0.9107344 , 0.7381775 ],
       [0.10953762, 0.39404439, 0.        ],
       [0.80039887, 0.12229682, 0.76424824]])

In [8]: im = img_as_ubyte(im)  # 8bit

In [9]: im
Out[9]: 
array([[255, 232, 188],
       [ 28, 100,   0],
       [204,  31, 195]], dtype=uint8)
```

If this is black & white image with  more than 256 shades of grey, I would recommend to use 16bit PNG format and rescale it to range (0, 65535).

If you have more similar images, you can use custom in_range, so that rescaling is consistent in all images, as Guang recommends.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
from skimage import img_as_uint
from imageio import imwrite


im = np.linspace(-40,288,10000).reshape(100,100)
im = rescale_intensity(im, in_range=(-100,400), out_range=(0,1))
im = img_as_uint(im)  # 16bit
imwrite("image.png", im)
```

EDIT: If you do not want to use scikit-image, you can define similar function like this:

```
def rescale_intensity(arr, in_range=None, out_range=(0, 1)):
    """Normalize numpy array.
    Returns: float array
    """
    imin, imax = in_range if in_range is not None else (np.min(arr), np.max(arr))
    omin, omax = out_range
    if imin == imax:
        raise ValueError("Cannot rescale array, imin == imax")
    else:
        z = omin + omax * ((arr - imin) / (imax - imin))
    return np.clip(z, a_min=omin, a_max=omax)
```