# Converting a grayscale image to rgb damages image

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a collection of grayscale images in a NumPy array. I want to convert the images to RGB before feeding them into a CNN (I am using transfer learning). But when I try to convert the images to RGB, almost all information in the image is lost! I have tried several libraries, but all of them lead to (almost) the same result:

### Original Image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(X[0])
```

[image]

### Using cv2:

```
import cv2

img = X[0].astype('float32') #cv2 needs float32 or uint8 for handling images
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
plt.imshow(rgb_image)
```

[image]

```
img = X[0].astype('uint8') #cv2 needs float32 or uint8 for handling images
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
plt.imshow(rgb_image)
```

[image]

### Using PIL

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.fromarray(X[0])
img_rgb = img.convert("RGB")
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
```

[image]

### Using NumPy

from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40119878/14420572

```
stacked_img = np.stack((X[0],)*3, axis=-1)
plt.imshow(stacked_img)
```

[image]

What should I do to make sure the images are converted without quality loss?

Comment: First of all, you should find out what the data type of the grayscale image is.

Comment: The grayscale images are NumPy arrays with shape (224, 224). Thanks,

Comment: And what is the data type? uint8? int8? int16? float32? etc.

Comment: Also, you should find out what the minimum and maximum gray values are in the grayscale image.

Comment: It is `numpy.float64` and the min and max values in the images are weird, `np.max(X) = 4387.0` and `np.min(X) = -126.0`. Do you think this is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but I suspect the values in `X[0]` are in the range 0,255. In

```
img = X[0].astype('float32') #cv2 needs float32 or uint8 for handling images
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
plt.imshow(rgb_image)
```

try replacing the first line with.

```
img = X[0]/255
```

This makes the values not only `float32` but also between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the images were loaded from dicom files so, each image had a different range. I was able to display them properly by doing this: `img = X[0].astype('float32')/np.max(X[0])`. Now I need to find a way to put all the images in a similar range so that my CNN can actually learn something 

Comment: @AryaMan My gut says that you're making images without a really light spot brighter. If I were you I would read about the format and avoid using information about the particular image to convert it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I am currently looking into it, I have loaded the images from a dicom file so I am looking for a way to read the images with values between 0-255 as default.

Comment: Use function rescale_intensity as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68513088/5239109